# How to Cut one word from textbox in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I have three textboxes in VB.NET :

TextBox1.text = "My age is"
TextBox2.Text = " My 22"

I need in textbox3.text = My age is 22

So need to remove My and just write 22

How can I do it?

Comment: You need to reject "My 22", that is not an age.  "It was 22 a week ago" is not either, etcetera.  Writing code to make sense of it anyway is a big mistake.  The Validating event is a decent way to screen user input.  Integer.TryParse() is good for converting text to a number.  Consider NumericUpDown or MaskedTextBox to enter the age.

Comment: How did My 22 get into the text box to begin with? Did the user type it in? The user can type in anything. Please use @HansPassant's comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use split to split textbox2.text and add it to textbox1.text

```
Dim s() as String = Split(Trim(textbox2.text))
textbox3.text = textbox1.text + " " + s(1)
```

The split function splits the value of the string passed into it and returns an array of values starting with index 0.
In your question, " My" has an index of 0 and "22" has an index of 1.

Comment: This assumes the 2nd string in the array is a valid input and it's consistent.  There's no validation to confirm it's numeric,  It also assume's there's a space or it will error out.  It also splits implicitly from a string.

This isn't good practice.

Comment: With the explanation I gave I think it would be easy for any programmer to figure out what to do in such cases.

Answer (score 0):

I would use RegEx to replace all non-numeric characters from the 2nd textbox.  Though, I'm not sure why you need the textbox1 text anyway if it's always going to be "My age is"

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

    Dim OnlyNumbers As String
    OnlyNumbers = Regex.Replace(TextBox2.Text, "[^0-9]", String.Empty)

    TextBox3.Text = String.Format("{0} {1}", TextBox1.Text, OnlyNumbers)
```